# how to get relationship with one-to-many on same table?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django and rest api. And I have two models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)   
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/categories")
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='part_of', blank=True, null=True)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    legislation = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    review = models.TextField(max_length=   000, blank=True)
    eaza  = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "category"
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)  
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/categories")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='animals')
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    legislation = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    review = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    eaza  = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "animal"
        verbose_name_plural = "animals"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And my serializer looks:

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['id','name', 'description']


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    animals = AnimalSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id','category_id','name', 'description', 'animals']
```

and views.py:

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all() 
    
    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def mainGroups(self,request):        
        mainGroups = Category.objects.filter(category_id__isnull=True) 
        serializer = self.get_serializer(mainGroups, many=True)
        
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('groups', CategoryViewSet)   


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

So if I go to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/djangoadmin/groups/

I get as output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 11,
        "category_id": null,
        "name": "zoogdieren",
        "description": "hoi",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "category_id": null,
        "name": "amfibieen",
        "description": "kujhkjh",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "category_id": null,
        "name": "vogels",
        "description": "kljhkjh",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "category_id": 13,
        "name": "roofvogels",
        "description": "kljhkljjl",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "category_id": 12,
        "name": "kikkers",
        "description": "kjhkjh",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "category_id": null,
        "name": "reptielen",
        "description": "reptielen",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "category_id": 21,
        "name": "slangen",
        "description": "slangen",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "category_id": 11,
        "name": "honden",
        "description": "hhhh",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 25,
        "category_id": 11,
        "name": "katten",
        "description": "kjhkjh",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 26,
        "category_id": 11,
        "name": "olifanten",
        "description": "kjhkjhkjh",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 27,
        "category_id": 21,
        "name": "krokodillen",
        "description": "l;l;'ll;;'l",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 28,
        "category_id": 22,
        "name": "cobra",
        "description": "cobra",
        "animals": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "indian cobra",
                "description": "cobra"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "cape cobra",
                "description": "cape cobra"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Chinese cobra",
                "description": "Chinese cobra"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 29,
        "category_id": 16,
        "name": "valken",
        "description": "valken",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 30,
        "category_id": 16,
        "name": "gieren",
        "description": "Gieren",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 31,
        "category_id": 21,
        "name": "aligatoren",
        "description": "aligatoren",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 32,
        "category_id": 13,
        "name": "meeuwen",
        "description": "meeuwen",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 33,
        "category_id": 22,
        "name": "droppel slangen",
        "description": "droppel slangen",
        "animals": []
    }
]
```

So for example zoogdieren with id 11 has many linked categories:

- honden category_id = 11
- katten category_id = 11

Question:
How to make a query that will filter for example on name zoogdieren and then the api call will filter the referenced id's?

So for example you fill in:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/djangoadmin/groups?name=zoogdieren and as output:

```
{
        "id": 24,
        "category_id": 11,
        "name": "honden",
        "description": "hhhh",
        "animals": []
    },
    {
        "id": 25,
        "category_id": 11,
        "name": "katten",
        "description": "kjhkjh",
        "animals": []
    },
```

if I do this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/djangoadmin/groups/11/

I get the main category:

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "category_id": null,
    "name": "zoogdieren",
    "description": "hoi",
    "animals": []
}
```

But I want to have the related entities with category_id 11

Comment: You need to write a recursive query in SQL, I recommend you to look into a library for this, such as django-mptt

Answer (score 0):

Now in  http://127.0.0.1:8000/djangoadmin/groups/11/ you just getitem with id = 11. If you eant to get all items with category_id = 11, you just have to make smth like that: http://127.0.0.1:8000/djangoadmin/groups?category_id=11.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).